# bash line Iteration in script

Tags: bash, text, iteration

I have the following data in text file

```
INSTANCES machine1    
Name    Berlin
Role    NA
INSTANCES  machine2   
Name    London
Role    NA
INSTANCES machine3       
Role    parser
Name    Dublin
INSTANCES machine4       
Name    Madrid
INSTANCES machine5
Role    parser
Name    Lisbon
```

I need to create the following output. How may I do this

```
machine1    Berlin    NA
machine2    London    NA
machine3    Dublin    parser
machine4    Madrid    NONE
machine5    Lisbon    parser
```

Comment: Use any one of a number of programs available on linux. You probably have awk,sed and perl installed.These can be used for this basic text manipulation.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while read -r line; do
arr=($line)
if [[ $line == *INSTANCES* ]]; then
[[ $count != 0 ]] && new+="\n"${arr[1]} || new+=${arr[1]}
else
new+=" ${arr[1]}"
fi
((count++))
done <file
new+="\n"
printf "$new"
```

**file** is the text filename